# How to update a state from an eventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to return the progression in percentage when the scroll event is trigger,
I dont nkow how to update the state to get the right result, and display it in the div tag
thanks in advance.

This is my script:

```
import React from "react";

class ProgressBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      percentage: 0,
    };
  }


  getProgressPercentage() {
    let maxHeight = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
    let percent = (window.pageYOffset / maxHeight) * 100;
    let progress = Math.round(percent) + "%";
   // console.log(progress);
    return progress;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", this.getProgressPercentage);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("scroll", this.getProgressPercentage);
  }

  render() {
    return <div> {this.state.percentage} </div>;
  }
}

export default ProgressBar;
```

Comment: You have to set the state with `this.setState` when you are returning your progress. That way, `this.state.percentage` is always up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.setState()` ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), [resource](https://css-tricks.com/understanding-react-setstate/))

```
getProgressPercentage() {
  let maxHeight = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  let percent = (window.pageYOffset / maxHeight) * 100;
  let progress = Math.round(percent) + "%";
  // console.log(progress);
  this.setState({ percentage: progress })
  return progress;
}

componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener("scroll", () => this.getProgressPercentage());
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  document.removeEventListener("scroll", () => this.getProgressPercentage());
}
```

Why your code cannot work as you intend:

When you write this:

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", this.getProgressPercentage)
```

`this.getProgressPercentage()` will NOT be executed as a method of your component, rather as a function. Meaning `this` will not be what you think : it will NOT be your component. Therefore there will be no `setState` on `this`. Hence the error you get: `this.setState is not a function`.

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md) about `this` in JavaScript, and here about [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: thanks for your answers , but i already tried with ``` this.setState``` before posting the question, and its not working at all, this is the error i get :     **ProgressBar.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.getProgressPercentage (ProgressBar.js:15)**

Comment: Have you tried it? Look at the code I wrote, note the difference from your code in the use of arrow functions, `this` is important (pun intended).

Comment: @TedajoPhilippe I updated my answer to add explanation

Comment: Oooooh right , you really right ! thanks again @laruiss

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setState`:

```
getProgressPercentage() {
  let maxHeight = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  let percentage = (window.pageYOffset / maxHeight) * 100;
  this.setState({ percentage });
}
```

which will trigger a rerender with the correct value of percentage.
I removed the progress variable because in my opinion it should be in the render.

Answer (score 0):

Use  setState, reference : [Description](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-does-setstate-do)

```js
this.setState((state, props) => {
  return {counter: state.counter + props.step};
});
```

```js
getProgressPercentage() {
  let maxHeight = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  let percent = (window.pageYOffset / maxHeight) * 100;
  let progress = Math.round(percent) + "%";
  this.setState({ percentage })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use setState  method on instance like below.

```
getProgressPercentage() {
  //your code
  this.setState({ percentage });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers, this is the solution i found ,anyway i dont understand why "setState" not working without "**requestAnimationFrame**' in this conxtext.

```
getProgressPercentage() {
    let maxHeight = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
    let percent = (window.pageYOffset / maxHeight) * 100;
    let progress = Math.round(percent);
    this.setState({ percentage: progress });
  }

  lisenOnScrollEvent() {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        this.getProgressPercentage();
      });
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.lisenOnScrollEvent();
  }
```